# How to use namespaces in case of inheritance?

Tags: laravel, oop, namespaces

I am new to OOPS thus want to clarify things. I have this code below which works perfectly fine.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "admin controller";
    }

}
```

Now I don't intend to use `use` keyword as it is going to be used once also wanted to experiment and thus, I used the code below.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

class AdminController extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "admin controller";
    }

}
```

Now the above mentioned code without `use` keyword throws a `fatal error exception`. Why does that happen? In theory,I think I am doing exactly what is supposed to be done then why the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to import it from global namespace , below code will work fine

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

class AdminController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "admin controller";
    }

}
```

Use keyword import class from global namespace, but

```
class AdminController extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

it will import parent class relative you current namespace (`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin`) , so translated path will be: `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Controller` which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. `\\`  before App\Http\Controllers\Controller suggests that it is referring to global namespace?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: I think the translated path you wrote above should be `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Controller` maybe you can edit it.

Comment: Updated, Thanks!